# enums in molecular weight calculator

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

I'm trying to make a molecular weight calculator as a part of a chemistry app. i want to make it so that the user enters the text in a  textfield, clicks a button, and then in a separate label the result appears. Since molecular formulas are mixes of both numbers and letters, it is confusing me as to how I can do this.

to organize the elements, i have considered putting them into an enum:

```
enum elements: Double {

 case Na = 22.99

 case O = 16.01

 case H = 1.00

}

var array: [(Int, String)] = [(number, element)]()
```

where the "number" is however many of that element are in the compound. for example, H2O would be `var array = [(2, H), (1, O)]`

then i thought I would append to the array whatever elements are in the textfield. for example, if it were sodium hydroxide, NaOH, the array would read: `var array = [(1, Na), (1, 0), (1, H)]`

then i would do a for loop to count the total value and add it together and print that value in a label.

the part I am having trouble with is how to append the items to the array based on whatever is in the text field. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: There's an interesting text parsing problem here but not enough information to act on it. Here you have an idea of how you might structure your data, that's great, now show us what input you want to support in your text field and what data structure you want to generate from it. With some example use cases in front of us we can all start to think through how you might convert text into structured data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings as the raw values for your enums but then you can't store the molecular weights in the enums:

```
enum elements: String {
  case Na = "Na"
  case H = "H"
  case O = "O"
}

let sodium = elements(rawValue: "Na")

println(sodium!.rawValue) // => "Na"
```

So now you can convert between a string and a concrete enum. You can use that to make a dictionary to associate the enums with the molecular weights:

```
let molecularWeights:[elements: Double] = [
  .Na: 22.99,
  .O: 16.01,
  .H: 1.00
]

println(molecularWeights[.Na]!) // => "22.99"
```